# How to display a section only to anonymous user in managed developer portal

Tags: azure-api-management

I want to display a section of text only to anonymous user, but could not find any option for it.

An option to display a section only to anonymous or authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature called "Developer Portal Content Access Control" that is currently in private preview this will allow you to achieve what you're trying to do. We anticipate the feature will be available in public preview by the end of this year. you can monitor APIM release page for announcements of when the feature is available: https://github.com/Azure/API-Management/releases